# Reverse association for belongs_to - has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

One thing about active record that has been confusing me (I'm still kinda new with rails).  I'm doing a migration like so:

```
def up
    change_table :slide do |t|
        t.references => :slideable, :polymorphic => true
  end
end
```

and then I'll modify my models thus:

```
class Slide < BaseModel
  ...
  belongs_to :slideable, :polymorphic=>true
end

class Painting < BaseModel
  ...
  has_one :slide, :as => :slideable
end

class Paper < BaseModel
  ...
  has_one :slide, :as => :slideable
end
```

Do I also have to do a migration for the has_one relationships on Painting and Paper in order to be able to use both sides of the association?

```
slide.painting.name
slide.paper.title
painting.slide.name
paper.slide.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `has_one` does not affect your database. `belongs_to` is what will actually create a foreign key field in your table, that is why you need a migration.

Comment: so i should be able to use both sides of the association as above?

Comment: No, with a polymorphic relationship you cannot reference `slide.painting` or `slide.paper`. You have to use `slide.slideable`, which will return a Painting or Paper object. `painting.slide` and `paper.slide` should work however. Also you have a typo in your Slide model, `:polymorphic=true` should be `:polymorphic => true`.